# как в js отменить распространение функции при click?

Tags: javascript

Первая кнопка она изменяет цвет, а вторая изменяет форму.
А если  нажать с начало цвет а потом изменение то она все равно продолжает изменять цвет или наоборот..

сначало нажать на кнопку потом на квадратики
две кнопки должны делать только свое дело
одна только изменять вторая только красить, а счас они после нажатия по очереди берут свойство и новой и предыдущей 
начинают одновременно изменять и красить цвет, а должный раздельно

```js
let btn_paint_bucket = document.querySelector('.btn-paint-bucket');
let btn_choose_color = document.querySelector('.btn-Choose-color');
let btn_move = document.querySelector('.btn-move');
let btn_transform = document.querySelector('.btn-transform');
let field = document.querySelector('.field');

let currentTool;

btn_paint_bucket.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  field.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      var selectedTd;
      let target =event.target;
      highlight(target); 
    
      function highlight(node) {
        node.classList.add('highlight');
      }
    })
})

btn_transform.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  field.addEventListener('click', function (e) { 
      var selectedTd;
      let target =event.target;
      highlight(target);
      
      function highlight(node) {
        if(node.classList.contains('transform-cilcle')){
          node.classList.remove('transform-cilcle');
        } else {
          node.classList.add('transform-cilcle');
        }
      }
    })
})
```

```css
.field {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inside{
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(151, 150, 150);
}

.transform-cilcle{
  border-radius: 190px;
}

.highlight{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn-paint-bucket" style="cursor: pointer;"> <img src="assets/icons/i1.png" alt=""> Paint </span>
<span class="btn-transform"style="cursor: pointer;" ><img src="assets/icons/i4.png" alt="">Transform</span>
<div class="field">
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside transform-cilcle"></div>
  <div class="inside "></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: что-то непонятно

Comment: сначало нажать на кнопку потом на квадратики

Comment: две кнопки должны делать только свое дело

Comment: одна только изменять вторая только красить,  а счас они после нажатия по очереди берут свойство и новой и предыдущей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот так, по нажатиям на кнопки меняем функцию, которая вызывается по клике на фигуру:

```js
let btn_paint_bucket = document.querySelector('.btn-paint-bucket');
let btn_choose_color = document.querySelector('.btn-Choose-color');
let btn_move = document.querySelector('.btn-move');
let btn_transform = document.querySelector('.btn-transform');
let field = document.querySelector('.field');
let currentTool;

btn_paint_bucket.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  currentTool = highlight;
});

btn_transform.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  currentTool = transform;
});

field.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  currentTool && currentTool(event.target); 
});

function highlight(node) {
  node.classList.toggle('highlight');
}

function transform(node) {
  node.classList.toggle('transform-cilcle')
}
```

```css
.field {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inside{
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(151, 150, 150);
}

.transform-cilcle{
  border-radius: 190px;
}

.highlight{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn-paint-bucket" style="cursor: pointer;"> <img src="assets/icons/i1.png" alt="">Paint </span>
<span class="btn-transform"style="cursor: pointer;" ><img src="assets/icons/i4.png" alt="">Transform</span>
<div class="field">
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside transform-cilcle"></div>
  <div class="inside "></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: тут можно еще упростить, основываясь на том, что в обоих случаях меняется один класс, но в общем случае это может быть не так, по-этому я не стал

Comment: Норм,получается весь смысл в переменной currentTool которой присваивается функция, что бы предыдущая прекратила свое действие

Comment: @recile ну да, как-то так

Comment: @recile не могу придумать как переименовать вопрос чтобы он соответствовал задаче